# Nested IF situation but make it DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m having trouble writing the right DAX combination of SWITCH TRUE AND OR function to fit the problem below. For the sample table below, this is what I’m trying to achieve: When date is between 15/05/2024 and 01/05/2024, and state is either WA or VIC, then Output is A1,
otherwise when date is between 15/04/2024 and 30/04/2024, and state is NSW or VIC, then Output is A2,
otherwise blank.

| date | state |
| --- | --- |
| 17/05/2024 | WA |
| 15/05/2024 | WA |
| 14/05/2024 | NSW |
| 10/05/2024 | NSW |
| 9/05/2024 | WA |
| 8/05/2024 | WA |
| 7/05/2024 | WA |
| 6/05/2024 | VIC |
| 1/05/2024 | VIC |
| 26/04/2024 | VIC |
| 25/04/2024 | WA |
| 24/04/2024 | WA |
| 23/04/2024 | VIC |
| 22/04/2024 | VIC |
| 19/04/2024 | NSW |
| 18/04/2024 | NSW |
| 17/04/2024 | NSW |
| 16/04/2024 | VIC |
| 15/04/2024 | VIC |

This is what I've tried so far but the 'either NSW or VIC' bit isnt working right...

```
Output = SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
                date>=DATE(2023,05,01) && date<=DATE(2023,05,15) && State = "NSW" || State="VIC", "A1","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Output = SWITCH(TRUE(),
  DATE(2024, 5, 1) <= [date] && [date] <= DATE(2024, 5, 15) && [state] IN { "WA", "VIC" }, "A1",
  DATE(2024, 4, 15) <= [date] && [date] <= DATE(2024, 4, 30) && [state] IN { "WA", "VIC" }, "A2"
)
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax#examples for more on the `SWITCH` function and use.